# MySQL won't start on XAMPP server

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a problem with my XAMPP server. I can start Apache, FileZilla, and every thing else without problems, but when I try to start MySQL, it just says

> Attempting to start MySQL service...

and it stays like that forever, like if it was frozen or something.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Here is an article you can refer to. It outlines a few possible causes and a few ways to fix it, which is very useful: https://blog.terresquall.com/2022/08/xampp-mysql-not-starting-on-windows/

Answer (score 7):

Check the log files for MySQL. You will find them in this directory:
C:\xampp\mysql\data (assuming standard install location of xampp)

Also check if no other program or service uses the default MySql port. 
You can do this by using this command:

```
netstat -an | findstr "3306"
```

If anything shows up the default mysql port is in use.

Answer (score 7):

I fetch the problem to start xampp services "mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files"

I delete all area_log files form xampp\mysql\data

after that I restart XAMPP than it works.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, you should go: Start > Run > services.msc > Apache 2.4 > Properties > Start Mode > Automatic > Apply > Start > OK > [Same as MySQL]

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to start `Mysql` on `xampp`.
Error message was:-

> Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and
>   delete all aria_log.######## files.   Plugin 'Aria' init function
>   returned error. Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>   Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.   Aria engine is not enabled or did not
>   start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was
>   configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables.   Aborting.

Just to go `xampp/mysql/data` and delete or remove the file related to `aria_log` and restart your `xampp` server.
Worked fine for me.

Comment: Worked for me also can you explain about aria_log?

Answer (score 2):

Resolve the issue stopping the mysql process in the activity monitor and  then restarting the mysql server from within the xampp UI.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the error log and check. For me I got this error message:

> InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
>   InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
>   InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
>   InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
>   InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
>   InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
>   InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
>   InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
>   InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
>   InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
>   InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
>   InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.

So what I did was I went to the mysql folder and deleted the `data1idb` file. After that it worked fine. The problem started when I installed Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

Perform

```
which mysql.server

sudo path/to/mysql.server start
```

This should work on *nix OS

eg `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start` for mac  osx

Answer (score 1):

OP did not provide enough information, however this (and other errors) can be caused by the default MySQL port (3306) being used. If this is the case, you can solve it like this:
Go to:

```
XAMPP Control Panel -> MySQL: "Config" button -> my.ini
```

Change the port number from 3306 to a different valid port number. I just used 3307.
You can find out more information about your problem by looking at the error log file. This is found here:

```
XAMPP Control Panel -> MySQL: "Logs" button -> mysql_error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

In The xampp folder you should find the start mysql batch file. Run it, The firewall might ask if you want to allow it through ( So check your firewall if it lets mysqld.exe through )

Answer (score 0):

Running the "setup_xampp.bat" file located in the root directory of Xampp did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is late, I'm sure it would help someone in future.

1. First run `which mysql.server` to know where mysql is located on your machine. After then run `sudo /usr/local/bin/mysql.server stop`to be sure that no other mysql process is running. If no other process is running, you would definitely get an error saying **MySQL server PID file could not be found!**. That's fine.
2. After then run `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start` to start Xampp's mysql server. When you go to the Xampp GUI, you should see that mysql status as **running**.

Please note that this is for OS X users.

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue. I installed xampp in D drive.

I uninstall and install setup as run as administrator. Again face same issue.

I searched and try lot of suggestion but no luck.

I solve the problem by right click on xampp and open as Administrator and xampp start working fine.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to start MySQL service. When I checked mysql log it said:

```
[ERROR] mysqld: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\aria_log_control' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
[ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't open file' when trying to use aria control file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\aria_log_control'
```

I checked suggested location in the log and file was present.

I found I was doing silly mistake, Since UAC is activated in my PC, I had to start XAMPP using "Run As Administrator".

It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps and this solves problem if changing port didn't help you:
(** By these steps don't need to reinstall xampp or loss your database**)

1. Stop all xampp services and exit application.
2. Move to c:\xampp\mysql
3. Rename data folder to data_old
4. create new data folder and copy whole content of backup folder to the data folder except "ibdata1"
   [image]

5) Select all files in data_old folder and paste into data folder (***Note*** Don't replace copied files and skip replace theme).