# MySQL in XAMPP v3.2.1 not starting

Tags: xampp

My MySQL in XAMPP v3.2.1 is not working. It is installed properly but this comes while running it

```
4:41:28 PM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

It never starts!!! Neither does any other error message come. All other services(Apache, FileZilla, etc.) are working but MySQL is not. How to make it work?? Can someone help me??

Thanks in advance

P.S. - I read [Xampp MySQL not starting - "Attempting to start MySQL service..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279442/xampp-mysql-not-starting-attempting-to-start-mysql-service) but couldn't find anything useful there

Comment: In what environment you are working? If windows then Sql server 20XX services might have running that's why your MySQL not working.

Comment: This is the first time I have installed something related to MySQL on my Windows 32 bit PC. I doubt that any other service was running. Still, is there any way to check whether a service was already running??

Comment: You can check by using net start "SERVICENAME"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily start your mysql just follow these steps:

1. open cmd in admin mode
2. type "sc delete mysql"   // without cots
3. uninstall xampp
4. delete xampp folder
5. delete all temporary files
6. restart your pc
7. intall a fresh copy of xampp

Its done. Enjoy!!