# MySQL does not start in Xampp control panel in Windows 8.1

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

After the successful installation of Xampp on my Windows 8.1 64-bit system, the Apache server is starting fine but MySQL is not starting.

There is no error showing in the control panel log. I changed the port `3306` to `3307` in the `my.ini` file in the `lib` folder, but no change has occurred.

[This is the screenshot of xampp control panel log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaqbJ.png) when I click on the mysql start button

Comment: may b skype is running.. quite skype and try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xampp MySQL not starting - "Attempting to start MySQL service..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279442/xampp-mysql-not-starting-attempting-to-start-mysql-service)

Answer (score 0):

let xampp run as administrator and open the services make sure you stopped running the mysql service and uninstall the mysql under service in xampp control and install and start.