# Can't open MySql service on Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp, port

I am running Xampp on my laptop, working on a local website. It was working just fine, but today when i start mysql service alongside apache, i am receiving this error below:

```
4:53:43 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
4:53:45 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
4:53:45 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
4:53:45 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
4:53:45 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:53:45 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:53:45 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
4:53:45 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
4:53:45 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

When i go in the logs tab i get this:

```
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 69450429; transaction id 42048
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200309 16:53:43
2020-03-09 16:53:43 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

And on `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php` i get this:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I cant stress this enough, i cant lose my work. I tried almost all the fixes i could find on the web, port 3306 its not used by anything, its not used even by mysql as i cant find this service on my pc anymore. I tried replacing pma with root in the "config.inc.php". Tried deleting temp and its still not working.

I add that mysql services are not to be found in my laptop (not in windows services not in procceses)

Comment: *"I cant stress this enough, i cant lose my work."* So you didn't make a back up?

Comment: No @Bashir that doesn't deal with MySQL

Comment: Have you checked the error logs as suggested?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xampp MySQL not starting - "Attempting to start MySQL service..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279442/xampp-mysql-not-starting-attempting-to-start-mysql-service)

Comment: I have been using this xampp for a month now, only now i have this problem. I have in the D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\mydatabase, saved locally, so i thought this was my backup. If i reinstall Xampp and just paste this database in the new data folder will it be ok?

Comment: @JayBlanchard that topic does not answer my question, as i said port 3306 its not used by any application(not even skype)

Comment: Did you look at the Windows Event Viewer? Without more information, it would be hard to know the problem is. There are some other files locally you have to make sure you keep in order to restore the database.

Comment: in event viewer i have several error from MariaDB: 
Failed to initialize multi master structures, 
Could not find target log during relay log initialization,
Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593

Comment: @JayBlanchard any suggestions? I add that mysql services are not to be found in my laptop (not in windows services not in procceses)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209395/discussion-between-catalin-and-jay-blanchard).